# does it matter learning main concepts or fundamental concepts of C#.net, asp.net with Old .net version like 3.5 or 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Please suggest to me if it matters to learn c#.net and asp.net`s main concepts or fundamental concepts which I need to work with the company with the old version of the .net framework 3.5 or 4.0 and while working can I learn new concepts with new versions of the.net framework? please help me

Comment: You'll be missing out on all the good new stuff - stop wasting your time learning 10+ years technology - learn the **current** stuff !

Comment: @marc_s: are their jobs available on .net 3.5 and 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic concepts are the same and hasn't changed. Some best practices has changed because of new features introduced in newer versions of C# and .NET.

I will say that you can also go the other way around and learn a newer version of C# and apply that to older, however some things will ofcourse not work.